# bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker showMeridian 2.6.1

Tags: angularjs

I have configured showMeridian in "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker" version 2.4.3. And it goes correctly.

But when I upgrade to version 2.6.1 it stops working "showMeridian", and I can not see in the documentation, that I have to change it to keep it running.

```
function config($httpProvider,$logProvider, toastrConfig,uibDatepickerConfig,uibTimepickerConfig,uiDatetimePickerConfig,KeepaliveProvider,IdleProvider) {
$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
uibDatepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
uibTimepickerConfig.showMeridian = false;
uiDatetimePickerConfig.buttonBar.show = false;
```

Can somebody help me.

Thank you.